# How to access the a reverse relation of a reverse relation django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I am determined to try get all the other users that replied to the same comment as a given reply. I have come up with the following python, however I am concerned this will do more than one DB call.

```
other_repliers = [other_reply.user for other_reply in my_reply.comment.replies.filter()]
```

I'm looking for a one-db-call fix.
The Psuedo-SQL logic would be something like:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN replies AS r 
   ON r.user = user.id  
WHERE r.comment = {my_reply.comment}
AND r.user != {my_reply.user}
```

Does anyone know a way that I can do the above SQL in a python django command chain?

---

Edit:
My models look like this when you ignore the anything that is not a relationship:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name='comments')

class CommentReply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='replies')
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='replies')

class User(models.Model):
     pass
```

---

Edit: I am looking to collect this final column in the following graph:

```
         /--- r4 --- u4
        /
r1 --- c1 --- r3 --- u3
        \
         \--- r2 --- u2
          *
           ** r1
```

Where r* are requests and c* are comments and u* are users
and the starred line indicates the r1 is ignored (as it was used to find the other r*s).

Comment: Can you please provide your model definitions?

Comment: I've stripped (what I assumed) the non-relevant fields. Please say if you think I'm missing something crucial to solve this.

Comment: `print(my_reply.comment.replies.filter().query)` to see how django is writing the query. [Django Debug Toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will also let you profile all sql emitted.

Comment: Hey @cowbert that's really cool (always wondered how to access the SQL query), but that can only show me what I can do. Not what I intend to do? Am I missing something here?

Comment: it will tell you what django is generating which will help you figure out what you need to change in your models to optimize it.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the speed of query yet. I merely want to be able to do it in pure django queryset functions. Please see the added graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
replies_with_users = CommentReply.objects.filter(comment_id=my_reply.comment_id) \
                                         .exclude(user=my_reply.user) \
                                         .select_related('user')

users = [reply.user for reply in replies_with_users]
```

This uses a join to retrieve all the users in a single query. The list comprehension just repackages those already-retrieved users into the format required for your use case.

**Sidenote:** If you are concerned about retrieving (but not using) the potentially large comment bodies, you could always stick a `.defer('body_field_name')` into the query. You can also defer unused fields from the users (if you need to) with the double underscore notation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible with a single query using the django-API, but it should be possible with two queries. Your common element is the `Comment`. First let's get all the replies r1, r2, r3, r4, ... to this comment:

```
all_replies = CommentReply.objects.filter(comment=my_reply.comment)
```

Now we just need the users from these replies

```
users = User.objects.filter(replies__in=all_replies)
```

Comment: Oooh I didn't think about that relationship, nice find.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following django command chain, can any provide a more elegant solution?

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=my_reply.comment.replies.values_list('user_id')) \
             .exclude(id=my_reply.user)
```

This looks like 2 queries to me however.

Comment: This is a subquery, not two separate queries. There probably is a way to do it with a join instead though.